# Trying to compare class fields C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, equality

Below I have the constructors of two classes. Student and Course

I am trying to compare the value of **_completedCourses value** from the Student class against the **coursecode** of the Course class.

**_completedCourses** is a dictionary of Courses and their grades. I am trying to find which course is not completed and print that list.

Am I going about this correct.

```
public Course(string coursName, string courseCode, char passingGrade, double noOfCredits, Semester semesterOfferd, int major)
        {
            this.CourseName = coursName;
            this.CourseCode = courseCode;
            this.PassingGrade = passingGrade;
            this.NoOfCredits = noOfCredits;
            this.SemesterOfferd = semesterOfferd;
            this.prerequisiteCourses = new List<Course>();
            this._enrolledStudents = new List<Student>();
            this._major = major;
        }

 public Student(int studentID, string studentName, Status studentStatus, StudentMajor studentMajor)
        {
            this._studentID = studentID;
            this._studentName = studentName;
            this._studentStatus = studentStatus;
            this._studentMajor = studentMajor;
            this._course = new Course();
            this._completedCourses =  new Dictionary<string, char>();
            countStudent++;
        }
```

```
  public void RemainingCourses() 
        {
           var cKey = _completedCourses.ContainsKey(_course.CourseCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Remaining Courses");
            if (cKey.Equals(_course.CourseCode))
            {

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, char> count in _completedCourses)
                {
                    {
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(count.Key + " " + count.Value);
                            //          Console.WriteLine("Course "  + count.Value);
                            count.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE!!!

The following line of code in my driver class achieves what I want

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID ");
                    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Clear();
                    if (input.Equals(id.StudentID)) {
                        id.DisplayCompletedCourse();
                        foreach (var sub in isdCourses) {
                            var cKey = id.CompletedCourses.ContainsKey(sub.CourseCode);
                            if (!cKey)
                            { 
                                Console.WriteLine(sub.CourseCode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know this for sure, but it looks like you could do just a simple .Where query on the dictionary? (docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thanks will check out Linq to compress code and made more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContainsKey` method returns a boolean value (true/false), so in your if condition:

```
if (cKey.Equals(_course.CourseCode))
```

`cKey` is a boolean but `_course.CourseCode` is a string, so this will never be true, thus this will never go within the if block.

Try to rewrite it like this:

```
public void RemainingCourses() 
{
    var cKey = _completedCourses.ContainsKey(_course.CourseCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Remaining Courses");
    if (cKey) // if cKey is "true", then the dictionary contains the CourseCode
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, char> count in _completedCourses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(count.Key + " " + count.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, please beware of the formatting, you are adding unnecessary curly braces. Also, this could be simplified with linq, but I kept it as close as possible to the original code.

Comment: Appreciate the tip. Got through